# force count to be zero in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `t1, t2` and the following query:

```
SELECT t2.year,
       Count(t1.id) AS count
FROM   t1,
       t2
WHERE  t2.t1id = t1.id
       AND t2.year IN ( 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998,
                    1999, 2000 )
GROUP  BY t2.year
ORDER  BY t1.year
```

Which results in:

```
+----------+--------+
| year     | count  |
+----------+--------+
|     1995 |      1 |
|     1998 |      3 |
|     1999 |      3 |
|     2000 |     28 |
+----------+--------+
```

And as you can see some years are missing. Is it possible to rewrite this query such that it results in?

```
+----------+--------+
| year     | count  |
+----------+--------+
|     1995 |      1 |
|     1996 |      0 |
|     1997 |      0 |
|     1998 |      3 |
|     1999 |      3 |
|     2000 |     28 |
+----------+--------+
```

I could use php and check which rows are missing to fill in the missing gaps, but that doesn't seem very efficient.. Any ideas?

### edit

`t1`

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`t2`

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| t1id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For example:

`t1`

```
+----------+---------+
| id       | name    |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |    john |
|        2 |     bob |
|       .. |      .. |
+----------+---------+
```

`t2`

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| id       | t1id    |    year |
+----------+---------+---------+
|      100 |       1 |    1995 |
|      101 |       2 |    1998 |
|      103 |       3 |    1998 |
|       .. |      .. |      .. |  
+----------+---------+---------+
```

Where after the combination I end up with:

```
+----------+---------+
| id       |    year |
+----------+---------+
|      100 |    1995 |
|      101 |    1998 |
|      103 |    1998 |
|       .. |      .. |  
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you show t1 and t2?

Comment: He did join the tables, the Sputnik-era way

Comment: Just a sec, i'm rewriting/clarifying the post. @DrewPierce hmm, is using `WHERE` that bad?

Comment: It's so 1990. I exaggerate. Use explicit joins

Comment: what if say to mysql - `or count is null`

Comment: if the left table has the years you can left join and use ifnull or coalesce

Comment: @DrewPierce the problem is that the table `t2` doesn't have the years... Any way to include the `IN` list in the query results?

Comment: Without a table containing all the years I think you are going to have to deal with the missing elements via code.

Comment: very common to have a lean and mean table with a bunch of stuff for the sole purpose of left joins. see my answer for consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table yrCheat
(   year int not null
);

create table t1
(   -- forgive lack of PK
    id int not null,
    name varchar(128) not null
);

create table t2
(   -- forgive lack of PK
    id int not null,
    t1id int not null,
    year int not null
);

insert t1(id,name) values (100,'john'),(101,'bob'),(102,'sally');
insert t2(id,t1id,year) values (100,1,1995),(101,2,1998),(101,3,1998),(101,4,1998);
insert into yrCheat (year) values (1990),(1991),(1992),(1993),(1994),(1995),(1996),(1997),(1998),(1999),(2000);
-- etc

select yc.year,count(t1.id) as count
from yrCheat yc
left join t2
on t2.year=yc.year -- and yc.year in (1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)
left join t1
on t1.id=t2.id
where yc.year in (1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)
group by yc.year
order by yc.year

+------+-------+
| year | count |
+------+-------+
| 1995 |     1 |
| 1996 |     0 |
| 1997 |     0 |
| 1998 |     3 |
| 1999 |     0 |
| 2000 |     0 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.year,
       IF(Count(t1.id) > 0, Count(t1.id), 0)
FROM   t1,
       t2
WHERE  t2.t1id = t1.id
       AND t2.year IN ( 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998,
                    1999, 2000 )
GROUP  BY t2.year
ORDER  BY t1.year
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a source of all possible years that your query could cover you are going to have to use php to do this.  One approach would could look something like this.

```
function getCountsForRange(\PDO $dbConn, $startYear, $endYear){
    $ret = array_fill_keys(range($startYear, $endYear), 0);
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT t2.year,Count(t1.id) AS count ".
                             "FROM t1,t2 ".
                             "WHERE  t2.t1id = t1.id AND t2.year between ? and ? ".
                             "GROUP  BY t2.year ORDER  BY t1.year");

    $stmt->execute([$startYear, $endYear]);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ret[$row["year"]] = $row["count"];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the empty rows pragmatically or in the query itself depending on the situation.

See:

[MySQL GROUP BY and Fill Empty Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252460/mysql-group-by-and-fill-empty-rows)

or

[Populating query results with empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812207/populating-query-results-with-empty-rows)

For some ideas.

Comment: Ideas instead of answers? What a *unique* idea! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: According to these links I should handle the situation using php. Oh well, I guess that works.